# What should I enter in Username & Password fields for recently installed Jenkins setup?

Tags: jenkins

Team,
I have just installed Jenkins on one of my machine. In between due to some other activity, I moved few min away. When I returned I observed my Jenkins page asking me Username & Password.
Note - I have neither created any user & nor set any password

My question is : What should I enter in Username & Password fields for recently installed Jenkins setup?

Comment: You can also have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39340322/how-to-reset-the-use-password-of-jenkins-on-windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see this

> Unlock Jenkins
>   To ensure Jenkins is securely set up by the administrator, a password has been written to the log (not sure where to find it?) and this file on the server:
>
> /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/secrets/initialAdminPassword
>
> Please copy the password from either location and paste it below.

or something like this, then you need to get the `initialAdminPassword` and then login and then set a password. Please see the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38943610/1728790) to do so

Also, 
         `sudo passwd jenkins` should prompt you to set a password.